# Elasticsearch - check if the parameter is not empty

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

In SQL, we can perform the following in the where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE :parameter <> '' OR :parameter is not null
```

Is this possible in elastic search to check if the input parameter/value is not null or empty? I checked the exists query but the parameter is a field, not a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-getting-started.html) or using [Exists Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html).

Ex:

```
POST /_sql?format=txt
{
   "query": "SELECT * FROM bar WHERE Id <> '' AND Id is not null"
}
```